# How to use Lambda in LINQ select without join between two tables or more

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I've three tables

> Investigators: id, name, first name
>   Articles: id, name, date
>   ArticlesInvestigators: id_Investigator, id_Articles, order

I want to get only all the investigators from the Investigators table to have one article published:

In SQL it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Investigators i, ArticlesInvestigators a 
WHERE i.id = a.id_Articles
```

But how shall be in LINQ and lambda? Without join because only want the results of investigators table.

Comment: What you have tried? Show some attempted code and specifically ask where you are stucked.

Comment: By lambda you mean the 'Method syntax' ?

Comment: The question is very confusing. Why don't you want to do a JOIN? If that's what works in SQL, why isn't it what you want in LINQ? Also, why does your SQL JOIN on the `id_Articles` column from `ArticlesInvestigators`? Just from the column names, it seems like `id_Investigator` would be more appropriate. Where in the SQL does it restrict the results to those investigators with just one article published? You should clearly document each column in your table descriptions.

Comment: Isn't that sql doing an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question or not but try this way and tell us if it work or not :

1) you need to make  FOREIGN KEY between your tables 
2) do you query in C# 
3) then you can get you data using the relation between your tables